# How to import node module with same name?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, require

This is for an electron app. I'm trying to import the nodejs `http` module, but doing `require('http')` seems to load the `stream-http` module instead. There is probably a dependency somewhere using it. I'm basically trying to do `http.createServer()` in the electron app. The app is set up like this...

There is a `BrowserWindow` with the property: `webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true, webSecurity: false, }`. This `BrowserWindow` renderer has a react component, and this statement somewhere in the constructor: `console.log(require('http'));`
The output looks like this:

```
{request: ƒ, get: ƒ, ClientRequest: ƒ, IncomingMessage: ƒ, Agent: ƒ, …}
Agent: ƒ ()
ClientRequest: ƒ (opts)
IncomingMessage: ƒ (xhr, response, mode, fetchTimer)
METHODS: (26) ["CHECKOUT", "CONNECT", "COPY", "DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "LOCK", ...
get: ƒ (opts, cb)
globalAgent: push../node_modules/stream-http/index.js.http.Agent {}
request: ƒ (opts, cb)
__proto__: Object
```

Basically this is loading the `http-stream` module. How can I explicitly load the original nodejs `http` module?

*Bonus question: doing `require('http')` in the developer tools window gives me the original nodejs http module. Why is that?*

Answer (score 1):

How did you generate your application? And where do you require your "http" module?

Please try to setup your application from this guide https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app#trying-this-example.

After that go to your main.js file and on top do

```
const server = require("http")
console.log(server)
```

I tried the above and got the http server module properly

The stream-http is an implementation of Node's native http module for the browser. It tries to match Node's API and behavior as closely as possible, but some features aren't available, since browsers don't give nearly as much control over requests. If you have installed it by mistake check your package.json and try to remove it.

Comment: My application is generated with electron-builder. 'http-stream' is not in packages.json.

The 'http' module was imported from an renderer process, not main.js. Is the node 'http' module only available from the main process?